# Query SQL não funciona corretamente

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Boa Tarde,

Estou tentando puxar intervalos de horas existentes no meu banco.

Postarei os codigos para ser mais explicativo

Query:

```
    $user = "Diego";
    $pack = "0013-001 B515 MCA ENGINEERING SUPPORT SYSTEM";
    $date = "20-09-2019";
    $horai = "14:01";
    $horaf = "14:03";

         $sql = $this->db->select('hrStart, hrEnd, hdate, pacote')
                    ->from('horas')
                    ->where('hrStart<=',$horai)
                    ->where('hrEnd>=',$horaf)
                    ->or_where('hrStart<=',$horaf)
                    ->where('hrEnd>=',$horai)
                    ->where(array('nome_user LIKE'=> '%'.$user.'%', 'pacote'=>$pack, 'hdate'=>$date, ))
                    ->get();
    return $sql;
```

Meu banco:

[image: BD]

O Retorno:

[image: ![Retorno]

Vejam que no retorno ele traz informações de outro pacote quando ponho esse intervalo de 14:00 - 14:03 ou outros intervalos onde os numeros estejam entre horarios existentes, sendo que o mesmo intervalo não existe.

Comment: Se você quer um intervalo entre hora de início e fim, retira este or_where e o where logo abaixo, não fez muito sentido pra mim. Agora se tem uma lógica aplicada por trás disto você deveria agrupar o or_where e o where eguinte, não sei fazer em codeigniter mas isto ai vai quebrar a lógica se você não fizer o agrupamento.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizei a função `group_start()`;

```
            $sql = $this->db->select('hrStart, hrEnd, hdate, pacote')
            ->from('horas')
            ->group_start()
            ->where('hrStart<=',$horai)
            ->where('hrEnd>=',$horaf)
            ->or_group_start()
            ->where('hrStart<=',$horaf)
            ->where('hrEnd>=',$horai)
            ->group_end()
            ->group_end()
            ->where(array('nome_user LIKE'=> '%'.$user[0].'%', 'pacote'=>$pack, 'hdate'=>$date, ))
            ->get();
    return $sql;
```